# Cluster Autoscaler Crash: Unable to build proper template node

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services

My Cluster Autoscaler (CAS) Pod V.1.17 stops working when it restarts and a Autoscaling Group (ASG) is scaled to 0. CAS enters a loop with the following message:

```
utils.go:126] Unable to build proper template node for my-nodegroup-NodeGroup-XXXXXX: ASG "eksctl-my-nodegroup-NodeGroup-XXXXXXX" uses the unknown EC2 instance type "c6i.8xlarge"

static_autoscaler.go:226] Failed to get node infos for groups: ASG "my-nodegroup-NodeGroup-XXXXXX" uses the unknown EC2 instance type "c6i.8xlarge"
```

This happens even though another ASG with replicas > 0 has exactly the same instance type.

At CAS start, it indicates that:

```
aws_cloud_provider.go:371] Successfully load 626 EC2 Instance Types: [...c6i.x8large,...]
```

which I guess should allow it to build a proper template.

I had to manually remove the unused ASG from CAS operation by deleting the following tags from ASG:

```
k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/sports-models-dev-eks: owned
k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled: true
```

But I'd like a solution which does not require to remove the ASG from the CAS workflow.

**Questions:**

1. How can I prevent my CAS from crashing when ASG is scaled to 0?
2. How does the templating process works and why the loading of the EC2 instance types, including the c6i.8xlarge is not enough for CAS to keep working?